# How to change to 24 hour format in datatables in R Shiny

Tags: r, datetime, datatable, dt

Just like most people, time date format is also not my favorite topic in R, and is once again giving me more trouble than I bargained for.

In follow-up of this question: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651789/changing-time-and-dateformat-to-show-correct-format-on-shiny-dashboard)

I got rid of the 'T' and 'Z' with `'toLocaleString'`but now my  `datatable` is showing times in AM and PM, while I just want to see the original 24h times.

I'm running the app in google chrome, and my output looks like this at the moment:

[image]

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)

  data <- structure(list(DATUM = structure(c(1490738402, 1490738436, 1490738440, 
                                             1490738444, 1490738447, 1490738451, 1490738455, 1490738459, 1490738463, 
                                             1490738467), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CEST"), NUMMER = c(19, 
                                                                                                                      20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)), .Names = c("DATUM", "NUMMER"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

  tz <- Sys.timezone()                                                                                                    
  data$DATUM <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$DATUM), tz=tz)

  ui=fluidPage(

    dataTableOutput("tab")
  )

  server= function(input, output,session) {

    output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data,rownames=TRUE, filter="top", class = 'cell-border stripe') %>%
        formatDate(1, method = 'toLocaleString')})


  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the `method` argument in `DT::formatDate` to a different date-time format, check `?DT::formatDate` or [DT Helper Functions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html). If none of these methods gives the right output, you can manually format the date-time output with `format`, e.g.

```r
data$DATUM <- format(data$DATUM, "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
#>  [1] "28/03/2017, 22:00:02" "28/03/2017, 22:00:36" "28/03/2017, 22:00:40"
#>  [4] "28/03/2017, 22:00:44" "28/03/2017, 22:00:47" "28/03/2017, 22:00:51"
#>  [7] "28/03/2017, 22:00:55" "28/03/2017, 22:00:59" "28/03/2017, 22:01:03"
#> [10] "28/03/2017, 22:01:07"
```

If you do not want to change the POSIXct-values in the original data.frame, you could update the date-time format only inside the render-function. Below just one way of doing it with `dplyr`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

data <- structure(list(DATUM = structure(c(1490738402, 1490738436, 1490738440, 
                                           1490738444, 1490738447, 1490738451, 1490738455, 1490738459, 1490738463, 
                                           1490738467), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CEST"), NUMMER = c(19, 
                                                                                                                    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)), .Names = c("DATUM", "NUMMER"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

tz <- Sys.timezone()                                                                                                    
data$DATUM <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$DATUM), tz=tz)

ui=fluidPage(

  dataTableOutput("tab")
)

server= function(input, output,session) {

  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({

    mutate(data, DATUM = format(DATUM, "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")) %>%
    datatable(rownames=TRUE, filter="top", class = 'cell-border stripe')

    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that in your specific example, if the dates are not necessarily required to be POSIXct class, it might be sufficient to just parse the dates as strings directly:

```r
data <- structure(list(DATUM = structure(c(1490738402, 1490738436, 1490738440, 
                                           1490738444, 1490738447, 1490738451, 1490738455, 1490738459, 1490738463, 
                                           1490738467), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CEST"), NUMMER = c(19, 
                                                                                                                    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)), .Names = c("DATUM", "NUMMER"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

(data$DATUM <- as.character(data$DATUM))
#>  [1] "2017-03-28 22:00:02" "2017-03-28 22:00:36" "2017-03-28 22:00:40"
#>  [4] "2017-03-28 22:00:44" "2017-03-28 22:00:47" "2017-03-28 22:00:51"
#>  [7] "2017-03-28 22:00:55" "2017-03-28 22:00:59" "2017-03-28 22:01:03"
#> [10] "2017-03-28 22:01:07"
```

Comment: I finally went with your plan B since non of the formatDate  options gave me the "2017-03-28 22:00:02" format in the app

Comment: I am also struggling to change from AM/PM to a 24 hour format. Seems the only way is to mutate date to string format. Hope the sorting works.